# Shell-Script:Create File List Based on Certain Charachter

Tags: linux, shell

I need to create one file list for below files:

APPLE_001

APPLE_002

BBB_004

APPLE_003

I need to create file_list only for

APPLE_001

APPLE_002

APPLE_003

Thanks,
Ipsita

Comment: Do you want content of APPLE* file into one file or you want the filename like APPLE* in one file?

Answer (score 0):

Your specifications are not that narrow, but here a **bash** script that match your request :

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ $# < 2 ]]
then
    echo "[ERROR] this script expects two arguments, input file and output file" >&2
    exit 1
fi

input_file=$1
output_file=$2

if [[ ! -f $input_file ]]
then
    echo "[ERROR] your input file '$input_file' is missing" >&2
    exit 1
fi

if [[ -f $output_file ]]
then
    echo "[ERROR] your output file '$ouput_file' already exists please move it away" >&2
    exit 1
fi

while read LINE
do
    if [[ $LINE =~ APPLE_[0-9]+ ]]
    then
    echo $LINE >> $output_file
    else
    echo "'$LINE' does not match expected pattern, skip it"
    fi
done < $input_file

if [[ -f $ouput_file ]]
then
    echo "'$output_file' generated."
else
    echo "[WARNING] no pattern found in '$input_file' no file generated"
fi
```

make it executable ( chmod +x ./list_starting_with.sh  )

run it with ./list_starting_with.sh file_in.txt file_out.txt